# Orthographe de « Leur(s) regard(s) se croise(nt) »

Tags: accord, pluriel, conjugaison

Quelle est l'orthographe correcte de cette phrase ?
J'ai toujours appris qu'on ne mettait pas de *s* à *leur* s'il n'y en avait qu'un. Ici, chaque personne a donc un seul regard.

> - *Leur regard se croisent*
> - *Leur regards se croisent*
> - *Leur regard se croise*

Comment: J'ai un autre exemple venant des maths: $f(x_1),\, f(x_2) \in D$, mais leurs images diffèrent. (leurs désignant l'unique image $f(x_1)$ de l'élément $x_1$ et l'unique image $f(x_2)$ de $x_2$).

Autre exemple: leurs têtes se cognent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**La première phase est fausse.** Tu as un sujet au singulier et le verbe au pluriel : Faute d'accord.

**La deuxième de même.** *Leur* est ici *adjectif possessif* (mon, ton, son, ma, ta, sa, etc.) et s'accorde avec le nom désigné (*regards* au pluriel).
Donc la phrase corrigée est:

> Leurs regards se croisent.

Attention à **leur comme pronom personnel** remplaçant un objet indirect (personnes masculines ou / et féminines).

> Il a parlé à son ami(e) -> Il lui a parlé.
>
> Il a parlé à ses ami(e)s -> Il leur a parlé.

Dans ce cas, en revanche, il ne prend jamais de s à la fin.

**La troisième est incorrecte.**

Il y a bien au moins deux possesseurs de regard (parce que leur(s) implique plus d'un possesseur), et qu'ils ne partagent pas le même regard. Il y a donc bien au moins deux regards. (Merci à  @Montée de lait pour avoir signalé ma faute.)

Pour résumer :

> Leurs regards se croisent.

Answer (score 0):

POURTANT ILS N'ONT QU'UN REGARD CHACUN!

Avis de l’expert – Bruno Dewaele, champion du monde d’orthographe, professeur agrégé de lettres modernes
Il est parfois difficile de déterminer si le possessif doit être mis au singulier ou au pluriel. C’est ainsi que l’on écrira aussi bien « ils ont accroché leur chapeau au portemanteau » (chacun n’a en effet qu’un chapeau) que « ils ont accroché leurs chapeaux au portemanteau (lequel, au bout du compte, en a bien accueilli plusieurs). Il va de soi que, quand le possédé est unique, le singulier est de rigueur. Mais quand il arriverait, au figuré, que l’on portât collectivement le chapeau, avouons qu’au sens propre la chose est plutôt rare pour un couvre-chef…

Comment: Cette réponse ne tient pas compte du contexte de la question. Pour se croiser il faut être deux car on ne se croise pas avec soi-même, ce sont les regards qui se croisent, seul le pluriel est possible : « leurs regards se croisent ». Si les possesseurs des chapeaux les échangent  au lieu de les accrocher alors « chapeaux » se met au pluriel : « ils échangèrent leurs chapeaux ». « Ils échangèrent leur chapeau » est bien sûr possible mais ça veut dire qu'ils ont un chapeau pour deux et qu'ils ne l'échangent pas entre eux mais, par exemple, font un retour du chapeau au lieu d'achat.